# Execute Python Script From Non-System Installed Python

Tags: python

I currently have python 2.7.1 installed on my Mac and there are some features of 2.7.3 that I would like to use with my current Python development.  I've downloaded the and extracted the tar ball into my /Users/mark/Python-2.7.3 but when I run my Python script how do I tell it to use the new 2.7.3 version instead of the system installed 2.7.1?

```
/Users/mark/Python-2.7.3
MacBook-Pro:Python-2.7.3 mark$ ls
Demo        Lib     Objects     README      install-sh
Doc         Mac     PC          RISCOS      pyconfig.h.in
Grammar     Makefile.pre.in PCbuild     Tools       setup.py
Include     Misc        Parser      configure
LICENSE     Modules     Python      configure.in
```

Comment: Modify the `#!` line to point to the new python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could either use the interpreter you want to run the script directly:

```
/Users/mark/Python-2.7.3/python2.7.3 script.py
```

or set the interpreter in the shebang line:

```
#!/Users/mark/Python-2.7.3/python2.7.3
```

third option, prepend the path to the interpreter to the `PATH` variable:

```
export PATH=/Users/mark/Python-2.7.3/:$PATH
```

Comment: I tried adding #!/Users/mark/Python-2.7.3 to the top of my .py script but I don't think its using the new install.  I didn't have a python2.7.3 in the Python-2.7.3 directory, any ideas?  I added my ls output of the Python-2.7.3 dir.

Comment: @c12 this looks like the source code, you'll need the binaries if you don't want to build it.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases — [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) is highly recommended. Install virtualenv, and create new venv, using -p key, pointing to another python version.

```
virtualenv -p /Users/mark/Python-2.7.3/python2.7.3
```

Then simply run

```
source bin/activate
```

And in this shell session, all calls to python will be done to isolated version of python with given version.

Virtualenv is a little bit harder to laern and use, but I'd suggest to use it always for python development. Keeping all projects and their dependencies isolated — helps very much. And for easy use of virtualenv, there is an excellent [virtualenwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/).